# Is it a good practice to add to a set of ActiveRecord results in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 queries that are very different:

```
Model.where(:a => '1', b => '2', c => '3', d => '4')
Model.where(:e => '5', f => '6')
```

Is it a good (or valid) practice to get the union the results as follows?

```
models = Model.where(:a => '1', b => '2', c => '3', d => '4')
models += Model.where(:e => '5', f => '6')
```

Working in Rails 3.07. This is not the actual query. It is simplified for the example.

EDIT:
Sorry, I was not explicit. The goal is to get the union (the sum of results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that there is overlap in the two result sets, you may get duplicate values. Try the pipe operator instead:

```
models = Model.where(:a => '1', b => '2', c => '3', d => '4') | Model.where(:e => '5', f => '6')
```

Comment: Works, but I don't know if it is more readable than `+=`

Comment: But keep in mind that if the two record sets include duplicate records, `+=` will put it in the array twice, whereas the `|` will only include items not in the first set.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a good point. I don't want duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
Model.where("(a = '1' AND b = '2' AND c = '3' AND d = '4') OR (e = '5' AND f = '6')")
```

It may not work for your particular case but at least only one query is produced.

In any case, don't forget to reject SQL injection.

Comment: This seems to work...but I think `|` is more readable...

Comment: You can replace OR by | and AND by & if you want. That works too. The most important thing is to produce only one query. Model.where(condition) | Model.where(condition) produces 2 queries.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you won't get the results I believe you want. Arel will combine these queries so that your model has to match all of these conditions:

```
:a => '1', b => '2', c => '3', d => '4', :e => '5', f => '6'
```

If that is what you want, this chaining is perfectly reasonable.

If instead, you wanted to combine results from two queries, then you'll probably want something more like:

```
models = Model.where(:a => '1', b => '2', c => '3', d => '4').all.to_a + Model.where(:e => '5', f => '6').all.to_a
```

Comment: This worked as well...but I don't know if it makes sense to convert to  arrays...